# Prevent new context after responding with new ones on Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have an intent with webhook and slotfilling enabled for validation and it have 4 parameters marked as required, so my server can validade the parameter value.

The strategy that I'm trying to use is: reset the context for invalid parameter value, so the dialogflow can ask it again.

Here is an example entering an invalid value:

[image: Invalid "Brasília" param value]

On responding "Brasília" the webhook makes a request to my server. My server knows that is an invalid value and respond with the context presented on the previous image.

This is the result:

[image: Result for invalid value]

Notice that the first 4 context match with the previous image, its everything ok here. But dialogflow adds another context. That context is a request for the next parameter, called "motivo" and if I respond back, the response will be stored on this param. After this, dialogflow prompts back for the "local" param.

The conversation runs like this:

> User: I want to register a call
> Dialogflow: From where you want to register? Aracaju, CAB, Itabuna or Salvador?
> User: Brasília
> Dialogflow: Please, describe the reason
> User: My network wireless is not working
> Dialogflow: From where you want to register? Aracaju, CAB, Itabuna or Salvador?
> ...

What was supose to be:

> User: I want to register a call
> Dialogflow: From where you want to register? Aracaju, CAB, Itabuna or Salvador?
> User: Brasília
> Dialogflow: From where you want to register? Aracaju, CAB, Itabuna or Salvador?
> ...

What I need to know: Am'I responding with the correct contexts? Is there a way to prevent dialogflow creating this new "registrar_dialog_params_motivo" after responding with a new contexts?

Obs.: I'm using a Nodejs server, responding the webhook as the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook) suggests.

Edit 1: I know that I can use an entity for this situation. However there is some cases that I need to make multiple validations on backend to procede, something like an user id, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent “Intent_Name” has some [input_context](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-input-output#input_contexts) defined already, then you need to set that context again as [output_context](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-input-output#output_contexts)  and reply something like you have entered an invalid location, and please enter again.

If the intent does not have any input_context, then you can simply reply you have entered an invalid location. Please enter again, and your intent should be able to catch that too. However, this can cause problems as well.

What I would recommend is having another intent “Intent_Name_followup” with an input_context as location_validation_failed in the logic. If the location is incorrect, you can set this in the output_context to reply to the user.